# Система голосования на Java, присваивание голоса объекту

Tags: java, объекты

Разрабатываю для итогового проекта многопоточное приложение голосования квартир по каком либо вопросу.

После создания класса Apartment не совсем понимаю как сделать, чтобы случайно генерировался ответ за/против/воздержусь и записывался к самому классу.

Само приложение будет вестись от модератора приложения, т.е. он входит в приложение с проверкой ник\пароль, вводит предложение и варианты решения. Со стороны участников голосования на данным момент требуется только генерация ответа (они якобы боты), чтобы потом использовать в качестве вычисления результата голосования.

```java
public enum Choice {
    NO, // 0
    YES, // 1
    DKNOW // 2
}
```

```java
public class RandomChoice {

    Random rand = new Random();

    public Choice ask() {
        int prob = (int) (100 * rand.nextDouble());
        if (prob < 10) {
            return Choice.DKNOW; // 10%
        } else if (prob < 55) {
            return Choice.YES; // 55%
        } else {
            return Choice.NO; // 35%
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class AskMe {

    public static void answer(Choice result) {
        switch (result) {
            case NO:
                System.out.println("Против");
                break;
            case YES:
                System.out.println("За");
                break;
            case DKNOW:
                System.out.println("Boздержаться");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать поле `choice` в классе Apartment и проинициализировать его в конструкторе:

```java
public class Apartment {

    private final Choice choice;

    public Apartment() {
        choice = (new RandomChoice()).ask();
    }
}
```

Таким образом, как только вы создадите новый объект `new Apartment()`, внутри у него будет лежать произвольно заданный результат голосования `choice`.